# Predefined django groups with custom permissions

Tags: django, python-3.x, permissions

I know in advance what groups of users will be. During development we often reset db that is obvious. But i wondering where is the best place to put this information and when put it to database cause i don't want to do that every single time via django admin by hand.

I figure out something like this:

I have simple map of perms on the basis of which I'm putting needed info to database via function.

```
GROUP_PERMISSION_MAP = {
    user_constants.GROUPS.ADMINISTRATORS: {
        Bet: ['add', 'change', 'delete'],
        Transaction: [],
        User: ['add', 'change'],
        Category: ['add', 'change', 'delete'],
        BetInfo: ['add', 'change', 'delete'],
    },
    user_constants.GROUPS.REGULAR_USERS: {
        Bet: ['add'],
        Transaction: [],
        User: ['change'],
        Category: [],
        BetInfo: ['add', 'change', 'delete'],
    }
}


def assign_perms_to_group(group: Group, model: Model, permissions: List[str]):
    permission_codenames = ['{}_{}'.format(permission, model.__name__.lower()) for permission in permissions]
    group.permissions.add(*Permission.objects.filter(codename__in=permission_codenames))
```

What are the best practice and how it should be done?

Especially my questions are:

1. Where this predefined groups with permissions should live (maybe exists some better way)?
2. What is the best way and time to put it to database ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case where you could use Django [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures) or [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-migrations).

In one specific project I also used a [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) to assure that some initial data was present, since fixtures were not exactly achieving what I needed in that situation.

For example, my `ensure_auth_data` command looked something like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates superuser, permissions and groups.'

    def _ensure_superuser(self):
        u_created = False
        u_updated = False
        try:
            usr = User.objects.get(username='ralf')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            usr = User()
            usr.username = 'ralf'
            u_created = True

        if not usr.is_active:
            usr.is_active = True
            u_updated = True
        if not usr.is_superuser:
            usr.is_superuser = True
            u_updated = True

        if u_created or u_updated:
            usr.save()

        if u_created:
            self.stdout.write('Created superuser "{}"'.format(usr.username))
        elif u_updated:
            self.stdout.write('Updated superuser "{}"'.format(usr.username))
        else:
            self.stdout.write('Superuser "{}" already up to date'.format(usr.username))

    ... some other methods here ...

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write('Starting command')
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self._ensure_superuser()
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self._ensure_permissions()
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self._ensure_groups()
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self.stdout.write('Command finished')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that in migrations due to the fact that `Permission` objects are created after migrations (I need them to assign to a particular group). Fixtures also are not the solution because I don't have primary keys of `Permission` objects and these pk may vary.

Comment: Hm... in that case you could use a custom admin command where you check if the users have the needed permissions, and if they don't then you assign them.

Comment: This command should be idempotent, so that you can call it many times without risk of side effects and with the assurance that after the call you always will have the desired permissions assigned to the specified users.

Comment: I have done that with custom command as you suggested. I couldn't find other solution. Maybe you found something in that time?

Comment: @Symonen for now I use it this way (just added example code to my answer). If it helped you, I would appreciate if you upvoted or accepted my answer.